# Making links clickable in retrieved tweets

Tags: python, django, api, twitter, hyperlink

In views.py I retrieve Tweets from a specific user that is then showed in the template, which works.

However, It's only raw text i.e. the links is not clickable and the question is what the best way is to make them clickable?

*Note 1: The links I'm referring to could be any links, but most likely Instagram links*

*Note 2: If possible I would even want the hashtags to be clickable.*

**code in views.py**

```
user = twitter.User
    tweets = []
    statuses = t.GetUserTimeline(user)

    for s in statuses:
        tweets.append(s.text)
```

**html:**

```
<div class="col2">
    <ol class="ol_list">
        <h4>Twitter</h4>
        {% for tweet in tweets %}
        <li>
            <p>{{tweet}}</p>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there HTML in s.text? Or is it just text?

Comment: @RobL: Just raw text...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used code like this to do something similar:

```
def linkify(raw_message):
    message = raw_message
    for url in url_regex.findall(raw_message):
        if url.endswith('.'):
            url = url[:-1]
        if 'http://' not in url:
            href = 'http://' + url
        else:
            href = url
        message = message.replace(url, '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (href, url))

    return message
```

And the url regex was

```
url_re = re.compile(r"""
       [^\s]             # not whitespace
       [a-zA-Z0-9:/\-]+  # the protocol and domain name
       \.(?!\.)          # A literal '.' not followed by another
       [\w\-\./\?=&%~#]+ # country and path components
       [^\s]             # not whitespace""", re.VERBOSE)
```

This regex prefers false positives to missing some edgecases. It also matches a trailing `.`. However I just remove it later. The hash tags will require another regex to match them.

Something like:

```
hashtag_re = re.compile(r"""
       \#                # a hashmark
       [^\s]*            # not whitespace repeated""", re.VERBOSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not very clear in your question which link you are referring to.

If the link is inside the tweet, as in the tweet is:

`You should go to this site: example.com`

Then you will most likely want to use regex to identify the links, and then splice HTML into the tweet itself before being passed to your template.

Turning this: `You should go to this site: example.com`

Into this: `You should go to this site: <a href="http://www.example.com">example.com</a>`

Hash tags can be done in the same manner.

Turning this: `Just walked down the street. #yolo`

Into this: `Just walked down the street. <a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23yolo&src=hash">#yolo</a>`